# How to group criteria or elements in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a column in MS Access where I want to group two of the five filter criteria to one new criteria by adding them. More precise, I want to add up "ANSWERED" with "COMPLETED_ANSWER" and create a new criteria out of it.

[image]

I tried to solve this with "group_by" but had no success.

Thank you for any help.

Jochbart

Comment: Just group by calculated column like this: `Switch([MyCol]='ANSWERED', 'A', [MyCol]='COMPLETED_ANSWER','A')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by a calculated field like this:

```
SELECT Sum(Table1.Field2) AS SumOfField2
    ,Switch([Field1] = 'ANSWERED', 'A', [Field1] = 'COMPLETED_ANSWER', 'A') AS Type
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Switch([Field1] = 'ANSWERED', 'A', [Field1] = 'COMPLETED_ANSWER', 'A');
```

In this case in `SumOfField2` will be summed values where record type is "ANSWERED" or "COMPLETED_ANSWER".

But the better solution - to create a table with statuses (ANSWERED, CANCELED,...), add a column with status type, join this table and group by column with status type:

```
SELECT Sum(Table1.Field2) AS SumOfField2
    ,Statuses.StatusType
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Statuses ON Table1.Field1 = Statuses.STATUS
GROUP BY Statuses.StatusType;
```

Comment: Hi Sergey, thank you very much. Can I just put your SQL under the already written SQL code from access or do I have to implement it in the original SQL code? Sorry for being so dump, I do not work much with SQL, I'm working most of the time with the draft view in Access.

Comment: You can modify your existing SQL query in query builder - add a calculated column with similar formula and group by it

Comment: I wrote it now this way:
`SELECT [123].KUNNR AS [Händler-Nr], [123].MBDAT, [123].ZZUPA, [123].KDName AS Händler, [123].Disponent, [123].Bezeichnung, [123].Region, [123].EUPA, [123].TUPA, [123].WUPA, [123].KUNNR AS [Anzahl-KDN], [123].LANDWE AS COUNTRY_SHORT, 

Switch([123].KUNNR='0000000008','0000000003',  [123].KUNNR='0000000017','0000000003') AS UK
FROM 123
WHERE (([123].ZZUPA)="005") AND (([123].EUPA) Is Null) AND (([123].TUPA) Is Null) AND (([123].WUPA)="X"));`

it works so far, but how can I put the rest of "KUNNR" into the column "UK", which aren't in the switch function.

Comment: You can use `Iif` instead of `Switch` if you don't have too many categories. It has `else` part, which can be used for the rest of KUNNR: `Iif([123].KUNNR = '0000000008' or [123].KUNNR = '0000000017', '0000000003', '0000000000') AS UK`

Comment: another way - use Nz function, Switch returns Null if no one condition was True: `Nz(Switch([123].KUNNR = '0000000008', '0000000003', [123].KUNNR = '0000000017', '0000000003'), '0000000000') AS UK`